# Variável inteiro que controla o loop

Tags: python

Estou fazendo a quinta questão [deste exercício](https://pynative.com/python-basic-exercise-for-beginners/):

> Question 5: Given a list of ints, return True if first and last number of a list is same

O código está abaixo. Nele, enquanto o usuário digitar um inteiro diferente de "-1", o valor vai sendo adicionado á lista e, depois, compara-se o primeiro valor da lista, `lista[0]`, com o último valor da lista, `lista[-1]`.

O código não funciona exatamente como deveria porque a forma que sei como fazer isso é usar uma variável para controlar o loop. Infelizmente, como a variável `num` só aceita inteiro, acabei usando o "-1". Eu preciso que uma variável controle o loop, para o usuário poder alimentar a lista enquanto ele quiser.

Porém, como números negativos também são inteiros, se o usuário quiser adicionar o "-1" na lista para comparar, o bloco acaba sendo encerrado sem o resultado. Estou procurando uma solução.

```
def verificaNumeros(num):
    num = 0
    lista = []

    while (num != -1):
        num = int(input('Digite os números: '))
        lista.append(num)
        if -1 in lista:        
            lista.remove(-1)#remove o -1, pois ele é uma variável que controla o loop, e não o valor que o usuaŕio quer inserir na lista.        
            if(lista[0]==lista[-1]):
                 return True
            else: 
                 return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se qualquer número pode ser aceito, então você não deveria usar um número como condição para sair do loop.

Uma alternativa seria aproveitar o fato de que a função [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#input) retorna uma string (assumindo que você está usando Python 3), então você define um valor específico (como por exemplo, a letra "s") para indicar que deve sair do loop.

Caso o usuário não digite "s", aí você usa [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#int) para converter o que foi digitado para um número. Caso não seja um número, você pode capturar o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) e mostrar uma mensagem. O código fica assim:

```
numeros = [] # lista com os números
while True:
    s = input('Digite um número (ou "s" para sair): ')
    if s == 's':
        break # sai do loop
    try:
        # tenta converter para número e adicionar na lista
        numeros.append(int(s))
    except ValueError: # não foi digitado um número
        print('Você não digitou um número válido')

if len(numeros) < 2:
    print('Precisa de pelo menos dois números')
else:
    iguais = numeros[0] == numeros[-1]
    print('O primeiro e último número são {}'.format('iguais' if iguais else 'diferentes'))
```

Ou seja, se o usuário digitar um número, ele é adicionado na lista. Se digitar "s", sai do loop e é feita a verificação se o primeiro e último são iguais.
Se digitar qualquer outra coisa (alguma outra letra, por exemplo), a conversão para número falha (a função `int` lança um `ValueError` e ele cai dentro do bloco `except`) e é exibida uma mensagem indicando o que aconteceu - mas ele não sai do loop, então ele pede que seja digitado outro número.

Repare que eu uso [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#len) (que retorna o tamanho da lista) para verificar se a lista tem pelo menos dois números (pois me parece que não faz sentido comparar o primeiro com o último se ela tiver apenas um elemento, e menos ainda se estiver vazia).
<sup><sub>*Para o caso de ter um elemento, podemos até assumir que o primeiro e último são iguais, pois são exatamente o mesmo elemento, fica a seu critério considerar este caso ou não.*</sub></sup>

Caso haja pelo menos dois números, eu faço a comparação e exibo a respectiva mensagem. Repare que eu guardei o resultado da comparação na variável `iguais`, e uso o valor da mesma para mostrar a mensagem de acordo com o resultado. Caso tenha ficado muito confuso, você também pode trocar o final por:

```
if len(numeros) < 2:
    print('Precisa de pelo menos dois números')
else:
    if numeros[0] == numeros[-1]:
        print('O primeiro e último número são iguais')
    else:
        print('O primeiro e último número são diferentes')
```

---

Outra opção é simplesmente ir lendo os números até que se digite algo que não seja número:

```
while True:
    try:
        numeros.append(int(input('Digite um número (ou qualquer coisa que não seja número para encerrar a leitura): ')))
    except ValueError:
        break

... compara o primeiro e último
```

Assim, enquanto o usuário digitar números, eles são adicionados na lista. Quando digitar qualquer outra coisa que não seja número, ele sai do loop e segue com a comparação entre o primeiro e o último.

---

Como você quer criar uma função que retorna `True` ou `False`, ficaria assim:

```
def verifica_numeros():
    numeros = []
    while True:
        try:
            numeros.append(int(input('Digite um número: ')))
        except ValueError:
            break

    if len(numeros) < 2:
        print('Precisa de pelo menos dois números')
        return False
    else:
        return numeros[0] == numeros[-1]
```

Repare que posso retornar direto o resultado da comparação `numeros[0] == numeros[-1]`, pois ela sempre resultará em `True` ou `False`.

Comment: O segundo código que você postou atende às necessidades(ir lendo os números até que se digite algo que não seja número). Obrigado.